# Keeping open an inherited pyplot figure after script finishes

Tags: python, matplotlib, qmainwindow

I have my own custom class that inherits from the matplotlib.figure.Figure class. It adds widgets and functionality to the default figure.

What I'm trying to do is, once the user plots data using it, keep the figure open just like the default pyplot.show() does and not have everything close when the script finishes.

The general usage is:

```
fig = betterFig()
ax = fig.get_axis()
ax.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
fig.show()
```

Where betterFig looks like:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class betterFig(QMainWindow, Figure)
```

So, currently, it works very well assuming the user slaps either an input() or QApplication.exec_() at the end of their script, or just calls their script using python -i. But ideally I'd like to avoid those and just have them run the above example script and have the figure stay open.

I thought about overriding my class's show function and place an app.exec_() or something in it, but then I don't know how to *actually* show my figure after that since I couldn't call self.show() anywhere in the class. Or maybe I could.

Any ideas as to how I can solve this? Thanks!

Comment: run `QApplication.exec_()` at the end of script - it will be much, much simpler.